# Jenkinsfile Groovy ; Trying to convert long url to 'link'

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here:

```
 message = "${message}: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [<a href=\"${env.BUILD_URL}\">${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</a>])"
```

output

```
SUCCESS: Job 'testing/spec [<a href="https://jenkins-prod.aws.website.com/job/testing/job/spec/120/">120</a>])
```

It should be converting the long url to just 'link'

Comment: The log annotator is probably escaping the HTML. If this was allowed, it could potentially be a security vulnerability for HTML injection. What happens if you just show the `env.BUILD_URL`? I think the annotator already turns those into anchor tags so they are clickable from the browser.

Comment: hmm not sure I fully understand but  I